# Non zero exit code for lsof

Tags: unix, lsof

I am using following `lsof` command:

```
lsof -iTCP -a -sTCP:^LISTEN -a -p <pid>
```

If there is some output this command returns an exit code of `0` but if there is no output the exit code is `1`.

```
echo $?
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening? Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour: you just get `0` if something was found.

From `man lsof`:

> **DIAGNOSTICS**
>
> Errors are identified with messages on the standard error file.
>
> Lsof returns a one (1) if any error was detected, including the
>   failure to locate command  names,  file  names,  Internet addresses 
>   or  files,  login names, NFS files, PIDs, PGIDs, or UIDs it was asked
>   to list.  If the -V option is specified, lsof will indicate the search
>   items it failed to list.
>
> **It returns a zero (0) if no errors were detected and if it was able to list some information about all the specified search arguments.**